# how to automatically insert javafx code like netebeans8 in apache-netbeans 13++?

Tags: javafx, netbeans

netbeans8  allow insert javafx bean properties with their setters and getters , but newer versions does not have that feature ( perhaps) . how can I do that in apache netbeans 13 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**make code via macro**

[image]

This example initializes a `SimpleStringProperty`  with their imports (if they are available), and getter/setters.

To implement it in Apache Netbeans, create a new macro using **Tools > Options > Editor > Macros**, name it, paste the code below as macro in the new macro you made, and finally create a shortcut.

To use it, create an identifier and then, with the caret inside the identifier, press the macro's shortcut. That was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> in my case, but of course you might select a different shortcut.

The macro can easily be modified for other property types, such as boolean, short, integer, etc...

There are two versions shown below. The one to use depends on your *"insert closing brackets automatically"* setting, which is shown under *Tools > Options > Editor > Code Completion*:

**with "insert closing brackets automatically" turned off**

```
select-word caret-begin-word selection-end-word cut-to-clipboard  

caret-line-first-column

 insert-tab "private final StringProperty " paste-from-clipboard " = new SimpleStringProperty();" insert-break
 insert-break   
"public void " paste-from-clipboard make-setter "(String string) {" insert-break
  paste-from-clipboard ".set(string);" insert-break "}" insert-break
    
 insert-break   
  "public String " paste-from-clipboard make-getter "() {" insert-break
        "return " paste-from-clipboard ".get();" insert-break "}" insert-break
    
 insert-break   
  "public StringProperty " paste-from-clipboard  "() {" insert-break
    "    return " paste-from-clipboard " ;" insert-break
    "}" insert-break
fix-imports  caret-up  caret-up caret-up caret-up caret-up caret-up caret-up caret-up caret-up caret-up  caret-up caret-up
```

**with "insert closing brackets automatically" turned on**

```
select-word caret-begin-word selection-end-word cut-to-clipboard  

caret-line-first-column

 insert-tab "private final StringProperty " paste-from-clipboard " = new SimpleStringProperty();" insert-break
 insert-break   
"public void " paste-from-clipboard make-setter "(String string) {" insert-break
  paste-from-clipboard ".set(string);" insert-break "}" insert-break
    
 insert-break   
  "public String " paste-from-clipboard make-getter "() {" insert-break
        "return " paste-from-clipboard ".get();" insert-break "}" insert-break
    
 insert-break   
  "public StringProperty " paste-from-clipboard  "() {" insert-break
    "    return " paste-from-clipboard " ;" insert-break
  
fix-imports  caret-up  caret-up caret-up caret-up caret-up caret-up caret-up caret-up caret-up   caret-up caret-up
```

Comment: I tried it in a new class. It appears to add an ending `}` that is not needed.

Comment: I checked now and } closes last method

Comment: We had [this](https://github.com/rterp/JavaFxPropertyHelperNBPlugin/releases/tag/1.1.1) in the good old `Java8` days. It needs to be spun up again.

Comment: @GiovanniContreras, This is probably nitpicking at this point, but I try to stick to the ideas the JavaFX developers use. I think they leave out "get" on properties. I think they would have it generate `public StringProperty camelCaseHereProperty(){ return camelCaseHere;}`